# on mouseover on a value of textbox js error that is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[image]

Here You can see that on over or while selecting the text value by mouse on text box I am getting an exception in javascript.

I am using html input field with bootstrap classes

```
 <input type="number" max="999" id="txtTaxPercentage" class="form-control inputFieldNumber inputFieldBoot" />
```

Can anyone help please.

Comment: looks like some compatibility issues between `jquery` and `bootstrap` library. could you replicate the same on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: is there any solution for it?

Comment: We can't help without seen the javascript. Probably will have to create a snippet so we could produce the error..

Comment: replicate on jsfiddle, so that we can have a look at it. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: ok...I will replicate it in fiddle

Comment: If want to update us once you replicate, you can mention us with a @ + our username. Are you familiar with this?

Comment: I made one but in fiddle this exception is not coming

Comment: (that._ignoreBackdropClick=!0)})}),this._showBackdrop from this line in bootstrap.min.js it is coming

Answer (score 0):

Hi all sorry I got the answer actually in my bootstrap.min.js
(that._ignoreBackdropClick=!0)})}) this line is by mistake written as 'that' in place of 'this'